# Python jupyter notebook after converting to html , numbering of markdown disappeared

Tags: html, markdown, converters, jupyter, tableofcontents

I used Table of Contents(2) of Nbextensions to create Table of Contents. And the titles were created using markdown.
Every thing is working fine. I mean , it looks pretty good in notebook modus.
[image]
But after I had converted the ipynb file to html file , then the number of each title dispeared . I used menu: File->Download as -> HTML to do this.
[image]

I tried to use another option "File->Download as ->HTML with toc" to convert to html. Although it generated desired numbering , this is still not what I want, because it will generate not only an html file but also multiple images file if there are some plots in the notebook.

Does anyone have a good idea?
I just need a SINGLE html file with everything embedded .

Answer (score 0):

The numbering of the Nbextensions will be present if you'll download the notebook to PDF (after installing the relevant packages).

Regarding the HTML version, I didn't find an answer yet and will be happy for help either.

Answer (score 0):

Notebook uses different formatting for the content. Exporting option only provide you to save your code. So, that you can send it to others.

Better save the data in the python notebook form itself to maintain formatting. Even exporting you to PDF won't provide you true formatting as the notebook does. But it will be better than HTML.

But if you still want the HTML format, you can format it manually as a webpage. May the formatting get improved in next version of nbconvert.